# media print with java-script doesn't print the whole div content

Tags: php, html, css, mysql

I have a `div(<div id="studentid1"></div>)`, in which the data is loaded via ajax call. my ajax code is:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    jQuery("#btnstudent").on('click', function () {
        btnstudent = jQuery("#ClassID").val();
        ExamID = jQuery("#ExamID").val();

        jQuery.ajax
        ({
            type: "POST",
            url: "getadmitcard.php",
            data: {btnstudent: btnstudent, ExamID: ExamID},
            cache: false,

            success: function (html)
            {           
                jQuery("#studentid1").html(html);

            }
        });
    });


});
```

my getadmitcard.php contains all necessary code and it is properly displayed the data into student1 div.

It is displayed the all content into my div but when i click on print button, It is displayed all content. Only 17/18 pages. It should be 35 pages(based on my query result). I mean the print does not display all div content.

Comment: I checked on google chrome. When i clicked on print button it is not display all div content. for example, my query return 35 rows. It is displayed into my div properly but print preview does not render all 35 contents. It is displayed only 17/18/20 (based on paper size-A4, A3, Letter etc.)

Comment: post your html-css code also

Comment: okay,  i will submit html and css code

Comment: <style>
 @media print {
 #pagebreak{
   page-break-after: always;
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
 }
 #studentid1{
   page-break-before: always;
   font-family: "Times New Roman";
 }   }
</style>